# How to style list elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div like so which will make up a nav:

```
     <div id="dash">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
           </ul>
     </div>
```

How do i access the list elements to add style to them?

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself?

Answer (score 2):

reference the div id then the ul lis

```
#dash ul {list-style: none;}
#dash ul > li {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: And don't underestimate the value of all of your elements having their own id's.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ID`

```
#dash ul{
/*for the ul */
}

#dash ul li{
/*for the li */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` to access the children.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/cqo4dz3r/2/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
#dash > ul > li {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="dash">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the id `#dash` and go ahead with `ul li` for the list items.

```
#dash ul li{
/* styles */ 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You *could* do inline styleing however it is getting out dated:

Just an idea

```
   <div id="dash">
  <ul>
    <li style="color:red; font-size:10px;"><a href="#">home</a>
    </li>
    <listyle="color:red; font-size:10px;"><a href="#">about</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Should never be suggested, always keep CSS seperate

Comment: I know but some people are awkward and someties you are working on tables...god I hate tables